# Habilitar/Deshabilitar Boton mediante JS

Tags: javascript, html

Como desactivo un botón si un input de tipo texto no tiene nada y al momento de ingresarle algo. Automáticamente me habilite el botón.

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required>
    <input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled>
```

js

```
if(mensaje.value == ''){
    enviar.setAttribute("disabled","true");
} else {
    enviar.setAttribute("disabled","false");
}
```

con eso que tengo de codigo siempre esta desactivado mi boton :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo resolví de esta manera, también valida cuando borras en el input.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <script>
        
        function mensajeChange() {
          console.log("change");
          const mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
          const boton = document.getElementById("enviar");
          console.log(boton)
          
          if (mensaje.value.trim() !== "") {
            console.log("Se muestra")
            boton.removeAttribute('disabled')
          } else {
            boton.setAttribute('disabled', "true");
          }
        }
        
      </script>
    
    <body>
        <input onkeyup="mensajeChange()" type="text" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required>
        <input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled>
    
    
        
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
// obtienes el campo de texto a evaluar y el boton
var inputTextMensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje');
var buttonEnviar = document.getElementById('enviar');

// se agregas un evento al campo 
// de texto para evaluar su estado
inputTextMensaje.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
    
    // se obtiene el valor del campo de texto
    // y se limpian los espacios al principio
    // o final del texto
    var valueTextField = inputTextMensaje.value.trim();
    
    // el valor de activado o desactivado
    // dependera directamente de si el campo
    // de texto contiene texto.
    // (los espacios no cuentan)
    buttonEnviar.disabled = (valueTextField == "");
});
```

```css
input#enviar:disabled {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mensaje" \>
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled \> 
<!-- 
  ya que el estado por defecto del campo es vacio, 
  el estado por defecto del boton es disabled.
 -->
```

Comment: puede que el navegador que utilices no haga diferencia visual entre un boton deshabilitado y uno habilitado, pero a nivel de _eventos_ el boton no disparara la accion, sin embargo, igual puedes usar el selector `input#enviar:disabled` para cambiar el estilo visual del boton con css...

Comment: ejemplo editado

Answer (score 2):

Usa el evento `keydown` para que JS sepa en que momento se presiona una tecla, lo cual nos es útil ya que de este modo:

**EXPLICACIÓN**

- Con un condicional simple `if` verificamos si el `event` del evento `keydown` ha ocurrido, si eso es cierto entonces quiere decir que el usuario escribió en en la cajita de texto
- Conoceremos la longitud del valor que contiene tu `input`
- Vertificamos dicha longitud y si es mayor a 0, indica que se ha escrito algo
- Cuando algo se ha escrito entonces accedemos por dentro de la función `addEventListener()` al elemento del DOM con id `enviar`
- Accedemos a la propiedad `disabled` del botón con id `enviar` y cambiamos su valor de `true` a `false`

**EXPLICACIÓN DE LA FUNCIÓN**

```
  let btn = document.getElementById("mensaje")
    btn.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      if(event) {
        document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false
      }
    })
```

**MUESTRA FUNCIONANDO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" id="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required>
        <input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled>
      <script>
        let btn = document.getElementById("mensaje")
        btn.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
          if(event) {
            document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false
          }
        })
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```